# passing int value to string value in listview

Tags: android

```
    TextView location=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvlocation);
    TextView weather=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvweather);
    TextView temp=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvtemp);
    TextView dewpoint=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvdew);
    TextView humidity=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvhumidity);
    TextView windspeed=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvspeed);
    TextView winddir=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvdir);
    TextView windgust=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvgust);
    TextView pressure=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvcondition);
    TextView heatindex=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvheat);
    TextView visibility=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvvisibility);
    TextView precipitation=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvprecipitation);
    TextView dailyprecipitation=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvdaily);
    TextView sunrise=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvsunrise);
    TextView sunset=(TextView)template_view.findViewById(R.id.tvsunset);

    location.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getLocation());
    weather.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getWeather());
    //temp.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getTemp_c());
    //dewpoint.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getDewpoint_c());
    //windspeed.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getWind_kph());
    //windgust.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getWind_gust_kph());
    humidity.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getRelative_humidity());
    winddir.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getWind_dir());
    pressure.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getPressure_mb());
    heatindex.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getHeat_index_c());
    visibility.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getVisibility_km());
    precipitation.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getPrecipitation());
    dailyprecipitation.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getDaily_precipitation());
    sunrise.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getSunrise());
    sunset.setText(Voicenames.get(position).getSunset());
```

i have here a listview of string value and i put comment on int value i cant pass an int value for it how can i pass an int value to string so that the null pointer exception will not show anymore?JSONboject are used here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
String.valueOf(Voicenames.get(position).getWhatever());
```

Comment: bah, you beat me to answering this by 1 second.

Comment: look at the comment i tried it but it doesnt work have a detail file saying the those four are int then getting it as in doesnt work at all

Comment: perfect code.you know how to put image from url?same problem with int

Answer (score 2):

Wrap those getter's in [String.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29).

```
temp.setText( String.valueOf(Voicenames.get(position).getTemp_c()) );
dewpoint.setText( String.valueOf(Voicenames.get(position).getDewpoint_c()) );
windspeed.setText( String.valueOf(Voicenames.get(position).getWind_kph()) );
windgust.setText( String.valueOf(Voicenames.get(position).getWind_gust_kph()) );
```

Comment: perfect.1 more thing same problem but with image view from a url i tried several tutorial but i failed.